# Removing weird space between arabic words in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on a Quran web application, I've recently encountered a weird situation, please take a look at the following URL:
http://www.silverlight4web.com/quran/test4.aspx

this is just a sample page which looks fine in Firefox, but Chrome doesn't display it correctly, as you can see, there are some spaces between verses, I'm going to remove these extra spaces. These spaces are randomly distributed between verses, I've also applied word-spacing CSS tag which doesn't seem to be a remedy. What is going wrong here?

Also you can here view a screen shot of the error:

[image]

[error screen shot](http://www.silverlight4web.com/quran/quranshot.png)

In [this URL](http://www.silverlight4web.com/quran/test2.aspx) you can view another copy of this page, but this time with a regular font (Tahoma). It seems that the font is the main source of this problem. Is there any chance to overcome this problem while still maintaining the font?

Comment: Having a look at your code, it seems that you are inserting some `<span>` elements and between these you are inserting text, and the spaces are there.

Comment: You are right, and do you think spans are sources of these spaces? I should be able to click each verse (each span), so spans are almost inevitable.

Comment: The spacing disappears when PDMS_IslamicFont is removed, so it seems specific to that font.

Comment: Is there anyway to maintain this font and still having no spaces?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet: Great works, I think the problem is with the `padding-right: 30px;` of your `class="normalText"` spans try to avoid it and see what happens?

Comment: I've set a total padding:30 pixels, I removed it, but almost nothing changed, the problem still remains

Comment: If you switch the order of your @font-face `src` definitions, the spacing disappears.

Comment: I think there's a white space in the verses number also `  (۱۰)  ` would be `(۱۰)`.

Comment: Thanks Rick, can you give me the correct order of src font-faces?

Comment: I've changed font-face src orders and now the page is displayed only in Tahoma font (which in turn solves the problem), but I want to solve the problem with the special font

Comment: @chsdk: you are right, there are two blank spaces before and after each verse number, but as you can see in the picture, sometimes there are several extra spaces after the verse number, and this is my problem

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  It looked Arabic, so I assumed incorrectly.

Comment: @Ali_dotNet I think it's the problem of verses data, because some of them are correctly shown and others not. I think you have to verify if they contain those white spaces or not? 

If it's not then try to put every verses number with its verses in the span element.

Comment: You should include a fragment of the content as HTML source and associated CSS, just enough for reconstructing the problem. Questions where the situation is described essentially via a link become meaningless to future visitors after the live page has been changed (and they are more difficult to address, too).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela thanks, but this link will be there forever! so all users can try to answer it,

Comment: @chsdk considering 1st part of your comment: all verses data are the same, but I think verses that are ended in the last characters of the sentence have no problem, while verses ending sooner have always some extra spaces (is it trying to make a justify?). But your 2nd part seems to be a good trick, I try to implement it, perhaps it help